# "Property ... does not exist on type ..." error when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I get the error when compiling a file with typescript:

```
Property 'qaz' does not exist on type '{ bar: string; }'.
```

With the following code in the file:

```
let foo = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?"
}

let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo;
console.log(qaz);
console.log(qaz.bar);
```

Based on example code on the page: https://zellwk.com/blog/es6/ in the section "Destructuring objects".

I was expecting to get the second string as output, but I'm a bit confused as there is another example on that page along the lines of:

```
let { fizz: faz = "Eugene was my friend." } = foo; // as defined above
console.log(fizz);
console.log(fizz.faz);
```

Which gives a similar error:

```
Property 'fizz' does not exist on type '{ bar: string; }'.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: That link is a lot clearer / better quality, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The article is about ES destructuring, which is also implemented in typescript. Typescript will however perform extra checks. One of those checks is that you can't destructure from a type that does not declare the property.

So, this will be an error:

```
let foo = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?"
}

let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo; //err
```

While this will work:

```
let foo = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?",
    qaz: undefined
}

let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo; //ok qaz is "I'm feeling manic!" because of the default
```

Or you can specify the type explicitly:

```
let foo: { bar: string, qaz?: string} = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?",
}

let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo; //ok qaz is "I'm feeling manic!" because of the default
```

The other part is you can destructure a property to a variable of a different name, so below, we take `bar` from `foo` and put in `fizz`

```
let foo = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?",
    qaz: undefined
}
let { fizz: bar = "Eugene was my friend." } = foo; // basically same as let fizz = foo.bar || "Eugene was my friend."
console.log(fizz); // "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?"
```

But the same typescript restriction applies, that `bar` in this case must be defined on `foo`.

This is generally the extra layer of type checking typescript does, you can't access properties typescript does not know about, either through destructuring or direct access with `.` or `[]`

The last part, accessing `console.log(fizz.faz);` will never be valid, `fizz` is not the original object, it is the string that was in `foo.bar`, so it will not have a property `faz` or `bar`. I believe this is a misunderstand of the source blog on your part, I did not find any such claim in the blog.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo; //err` should not throw an error via tscomplier. His error msg is from trying to access a property on `string` that does not exist

Comment: @Andrei he mentions the error as being `Property 'qaz' does not exist on type '{ bar: string; }'.` which is 100% a TS compiler error.

Comment: which should be thrown at `console.log(qaz.bar);` or is ts smart enough to catch it earlier? if he did not use `console.log(qaz.bar);` will the error still appear?

Comment: @Andrei the error occurs on destructuring not on the console.log, the advantages of using TS, consistent errors when you do bad things :) : https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IG8BQEMQEYEMBOAXBAEQDCOAdhAJ4wCuEADiHrHgLYQ4QCKdAlngDWOKKBABzAPzEANKgC+qVKEjIIARxwAvRCQCSAck5QQIYPwoSI7SvwDGAQmIQFe2DADcEIA

Comment: That's a beauty I've only had a few chances to use Typescript for small personal projects I didn't realize it would do that type of static analysis.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that if you're using interfaces, you can add `[key: string]: any;`. You *can*, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Isn't that last destructuring example backward? Shouldn't it be: `let { bar: fizz = "..."}`. See [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IG8CwAoCWICMCGATgFwQBEAwngHYQCeMArhAA4gGwEC2EeEAigwCWBANZ4ooEAHMA-KQA0GbBACOeAF4kGVACYgogqiB0YAvhlCRkuQiQPr1iMgFEGUkEYgB3PAGcInLTQBIIeOgB0pBCmTrAwANwQAPRJNr6CAMZ4wMBBvnicIDz+ltCCDrFw4fgEEAA+dS5uHkU+-oHBobqRGBkwVL4woOHAMFIAFPbqAJSJKWSUNPRMrOwwXDz8QqLikrJRQA)

Answer (score 2):

That is working as expected. You are destructing and providing a default parameter to `qaz`. It should work, but it seems like the tscompiler has an issue with that. You can fix it by providing the type `any` e.g.

```
  let foo = { bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?" }
  let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" }: any = foo;
  console.log(qaz); // I'm feeling manic!
  console.log(qaz.bar); // undefined
```

Comment: Worth noting that while `any` will remove the error you *can* get type safety here as well - see @Titian's answer

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Destructuring objects work.

Essentially it will look at the child properties of `foo` and assign new variable to them

> That must match the property names of `foo`

For instance

```
const Zell = {
  firstName: 'Zell',
  lastName: 'Liew'
}

let { firstName, lastName } = Zell

console.log(firstName) // Zell
console.log(lastName) // Liew
```

to fix your example you'll need to do

```
let foo = {
    bar: "Can you perform a Quirkafleeg?"
}

let { bar } = foo;
console.log(bar);
```

When you try to access 'qaz' on bar it cannot since `bar` is a `String`

EDIT:

To expand in your example

`let { qaz = "I'm feeling manic!" } = foo;` When you're assigning `qaz` a value via `=` it is actually just a default value if it is not found on the object foo.

In your example

`let { fizz: faz = "Eugene was my friend." } = foo;` you're trying to assign `fizz` to the value of  `foo.faz` and if `fizz` does not exist on `foo` it will default to "Eugene was my friend."

Comment: It works fine. The Typescript Compiler has an issue with unknown default parameters.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz just throwing `any` at it doesn't look like the behavior he's looking for. The underlying example is about accessing `qaz.bar` which would never be valid. He's trying to get `bar` and to do so he either needs to use an alias via `let {qaz: bar = "text"} = foo` or just use `let { bar = "text" } = foo`

Comment: Ah right, so it works in Javascript but not Typescript. That explains why it's on that page, which is about Javascript.